# Java compiler error. For loop not a statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I'm working on an assignment where we have to use nested for loops and pass parameters to create this ASCII picture of a tree. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with it that it's not compiling.

Here's the source:

```
public class Tree{

  public static void main(String [] args){

    drawTree(3,4);     
  }

  public static String drawTree(int n, int h){ //n is number of bodies, h is their height.

    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++){ //Number of tree bodies to create
      drawSegment(n);
      }

//Trunk
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk spaces
      System.out.print (" ");    
    }

    System.out.print ("*"); //Trunk Body

    for (int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk end spaces
      System.out.print (" ");
    }
  }

//Leaves  
  public static String drawSegment(int k){ //Creates the tree's bodies 

    for(int i; i = 1; i <= k; i++){ //Number of lines  

      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of Spaces
    System.out.print (" ");      
      }

      for(int s; s <= (2 * i) - 1; s++){ //Number of Stars
    System.out.print ("*");
      }

      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of End Spaces
    System.out.println (" ");      
      }

     }
   }
}
```

These are the error's:

```
Tree.java:10: error: not a statement
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++){ //Number of tree bodies to create
                    ^
Tree.java:10: error: ')' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++){ //Number of tree bodies to create
                        ^
Tree.java:10: error: ';' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++){ //Number of tree bodies to create
                             ^
Tree.java:15: error: not a statement
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk spaces
                    ^
Tree.java:15: error: ')' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk spaces
                            ^
Tree.java:15: error: ';' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk spaces
                                 ^
Tree.java:21: error: not a statement
    for (int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk end spaces
                     ^
Tree.java:21: error: ')' expected
    for (int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk end spaces
                             ^
Tree.java:21: error: ';' expected
    for (int i; i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++){ //Trunk end spaces
                                  ^
Tree.java:28: error: not a statement
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= k; i++){ //Number of lines  
                    ^
Tree.java:28: error: ')' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= k; i++){ //Number of lines  
                        ^
Tree.java:28: error: ';' expected
    for(int i; i = 1; i <= k; i++){ //Number of lines  
                             ^
Tree.java:30: error: not a statement
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of Spaces
                      ^
Tree.java:30: error: ')' expected
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of Spaces
                              ^
Tree.java:30: error: ';' expected
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of Spaces
                                   ^
Tree.java:38: error: not a statement
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of End Spaces
                      ^
Tree.java:38: error: ')' expected
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of End Spaces
                              ^
Tree.java:38: error: ';' expected
      for(int s; s = 1; s <= k - 1; s++){ //Number of End Spaces
                                   ^
18 errors
```

I think it has something to do with the for loop in the first method `drawTree` not being able to find h. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Say `int i=1` instead.

Comment: You might want to try this book on amazon. Java Beginners Reference: Quick Reference by Harvey Benson I bought it today and have found it extremely full of good quality code and facts about Java.

Comment: I have a book (Building Java Programs: A back to basics approach) and am taking classes on it. I'm actually really embarrassed I even asked this once I saw the answers. I have written hundreds of for loops already and for some reason had a huge brain fart doing this assignment and forgot part of the syntax. It's such a newbie mistake it's hurting me on the inside. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++)
```

With :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= h; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be

```
for(int i = 1; i <= h - 1; i++) {}
```

and so forth for the rest of the for loops

Answer (score 1):

In each for loop you do this:

```
for(int i; i = 1; i <= h; i++){
```

but it should be:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= h; i++){
```

With only two ; ;

```
for(init;condition;statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for(int i = 1; i <= h; i++)
{
    Your Code.
}
```

Note: This is the rule for FOR LOOP
for(initiation; condition; statement)